# Spring Data JPA : find enum field as String?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity:

```
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleName name;
}
```

And here is the `RoleName` enum:

```
public enum RoleName {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

I am trying to find a role by name and for this purpose, I have to pass name value in `RoleName` format (otherwise I get exception when I try to pass String):

```
Role r = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.valueOf(role))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(NOT_FOUND));
```

But, when a user request a role that is not available, s/he gets error:

> Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.company.model.RoleName.ROLE_TEST]

So, is it not possible to search Role by name in `String` format instead of `RoleName`? Because, user provides roles in String array and instead of casting to enum, I want to check if the role is exist or not in the database. Any idea?

Comment: So you want to throw a different exception?

Comment: How can you insert an non existing value?

Comment: @Unmitigated Actually I just want to be able to check if the role is existing in the database by using a string. Then, the rest is ok, I can throw "not found" exception.

Comment: @fredrick You can replace `RoleName.valueOf` with `Arrays.stream(RoleName.values()).filter(x -> x.name().equals(role)).findFirst().orElse(null)` so that it passes `null` when the role name isn't found rather than throwing an exception there.

Comment: @Jens How do you know if a user could enter a weird role that is not existed?

Comment: the inserting into the data base should using the same Enum, so in the database can only be valid enum values. In your case looks like there is something wrong in your application design

Comment: @Unmitigated Actually sounds good, but I am not sure what is the user requests roles and none of them not exists in the database. In this case, I should not continue to register user as there is no role and inform them. Any idea?

Comment: @Unmitigated On the other hand, maybe it is good idea to get all the roles from db and check if there is at least one match with the requested list (there is no need to go to db 3 times if the user send 3 roles for signup). How should I do this? What would you think?

Comment: @Jens I am sure that there is no problem regarding to entity relationships. The issues seems to be related to type mismatch and it is normal. Because, request is a `Set<String>` as user send the roles in the JSON as `["ADMIN_ROLE"]`. But the data type in JPA entity is not String.

Comment: Then you should check it in your bussines logic. I am sure there is a problem in your application design.

Comment: @Jens In any case, maybe it is good idea to retrieve all the roles in the database and then check the requested roles matches. Then, if there is no match, throw error, if not, then add them to Role set before persisting. Any idea? And example with Stream?

Comment: *maybe it is good idea to retrieve all the roles in the database* It is a good Idea to only inserting valid values

Comment: @Jens When I try to change `Set<String>` to `Set<RoleName` in the request, it gives another error as it is not possible to pass that type by JSON request. I do not want to change request pass style of the roles. But would think of using teh problem by Stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252300/discussion-between-jens-and-fredrick).

Comment: I solved the problem by converting the approach o `Arrays.stream(RoleName.values()).filter(x -> x.name().equals(role)).findFirst().orElse(null)` for repository. **Thanks a lot to all of you!..**

Answer (score 1):

You could set up your `Enum` like this:

```
public enum RoleName {

    // enum constants calling the enum constructors
    ROLE_USER("User"),
    ROLE_ADMIN("Admin")

    private String role;

    // private enum constructor
    private RoleName(String role) {
    this.role = role
    }

    public String getRole(){
       return role;
    }
}
```

Then you can search `Role` by name in `String`

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, sounds good idea, but now get another error : "Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Argument [ROLE_USER] of type [java.lang.String] did not match parameter type [com.company.model.RoleName (n/a)]]"

Comment: I suppose that role is a RoleName enum. So if you tried 
Role r = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.valueOf(role.getRole()))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException
??

Comment: Role is entity and name field of this entity is in RoleName type that is enum. I am trying this now.

Comment: Ok, so  Role r = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.valueOf(role.getName().getRole())) .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException might help

Comment: What about retrieving all roles at the beginning and then check if the requested roles match with these retrieved roles? Any idea?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have any problem if you used the getter function inside your Enum. It's also important to note that Enums are preferred when the inputs are kind of "fixed", for example if you could narrow down the possible values that a user could give as an input e.g. select a value from a dropdown menu. Nevertheless, retrieving all roles at the beginning is not a best-practice approach.